# Docker firewall issue with cBioportal

Tags: linux, docker

we are sitting behind a firewall and try to run a docker image (cBioportal). The docker itself could be installed with a proxy but now we encounter the following issue:

```
Starting validation...

INFO: -: Unable to read xml containing cBioPortal version.
DEBUG: -: Requesting cancertypes from portal at 'http://cbioportal-container:8081'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Error occurred during validation step:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/cbioportal/core/src/main/scripts/importer/validateData.py", line 4491, in request_from_portal_api
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 504 Server Error: Gateway Timeout for url: http://cbioportal-container:8081/api-legacy/cancertypes

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/metaImport.py", line 127, in <module>
    exitcode = validateData.main_validate(args)
  File "/cbioportal/core/src/main/scripts/importer/validateData.py", line 4969, in main_validate
    portal_instance = load_portal_info(server_url, logger)
  File "/cbioportal/core/src/main/scripts/importer/validateData.py", line 4622, in load_portal_info
    parsed_json = request_from_portal_api(path, api_name, logger)
  File "/cbioportal/core/src/main/scripts/importer/validateData.py", line 4495, in request_from_portal_api
    ) from e
ConnectionError: Failed to fetch metadata from the portal at [http://cbioportal-container:8081/api-legacy/cancertypes]
```

Now we know that it is a firewall issue, because it works when we install it outside the firewall. But we do not know how to change the firewall yet. Our idea was to look up the files and lines which throw the errors. But we do not know how to look into the files since they are within the docker.

So we can not just do something like 
vim /cbioportal/core/src/main/scripts/importer/validateData.py

...because ... there is nothing. Of course we know this file is within the docker image, but like i said we dont know how to look into it. At the moment we do not know how to solve this riddle - any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you still might need this.
You can access this python file within the container by using`docker-compose exec cbioportal sh` or `docker-compose exec cbioportal bash`

Then you can us cd, cat, vi, vim or else to access the given path in your post.

I'm not sure which command you're actually running but when I did the import call like

```
docker-compose run --rm cbioportal metaImport.py -u http://cbioportal:8080 -s study/lgg_ucsf_2014/lgg_ucsf_2014/ -o
```

I had to replace the http://cbioportal:8080 with the servers ip address.
Also notice that the studies path is one level deeper than in the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In cbioportal behind proxy the study import is only available in offline mode via:

First you need to get inside the container

```
docker exec -it cbioportal-container bash
```

Then generate portal info folder

```
cd $PORTAL_HOME/core/src/main/scripts ./dumpPortalInfo.pl $PORTAL_HOME/my_portal_info_folder
```

Then import the study offline. -o is important to overwrite despite of warnings.

```
cd $PORTAL_HOME/core/src/main/scripts
./importer/metaImport.py -p $PORTAL_HOME/my_portal_info_folder -s /study/lgg_ucsf_2014 -v -o
```

Hope this helps.